# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type

Tags: asp.net

here is i am trying to work.

```
List<MasterEmployee > masterEmployee = new List<MasterEmployee >();
masterEmployee = MasterEmployee.GetAll("123"); //connecting db and returning a list...


  foreach (MasterEmployee item in masterEmployee)
   {
      foreach (Registration reg in item.Registration) //<<<error here...
      {
           //
      }
  }
```

error here:

```
Error   2   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type Registration because Registration does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

i have a class called MasterEmployee and in it i have a with few props and few methods on it

```
 [Serializable]
    public class MasterEmployee 
    {

        //few props omitted  ....

        protected Registration _registration;
        [CopyConstructorIgnore]
        public Registration Registration
        {
            get
            {
                return _registration;

            }
            set
            {
                this._registration = value;
            }
        }
        protected User _user;
        [CopyConstructorIgnore]
        public User MyUser
        {
            get
            {
               return _user;
            }
            set
            {
                this._user= value;
            }
        }

        protected Student _student;
        [CopyConstructorIgnore]
        public Student Student
        {
            get
            {
                return _student;
            }
            set
            {
                this._student = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation provided in the error message is clear enough.  You are trying to iterate `item.Registration`, which is an instance of `Registration`.  However, `Registration` is not derived from an iterable type, and does not implement the `GetEnumerator` function required for custom iterable types.  So it cannot be iterated using a `foreach` loop.

But I believe either your naming conventions are incorrect, or you have misunderstood your data model.  Why would a `Registration` instance ever contain a collection of `Registration` instances?  If an item can have multiple `Registration` instances associated with it, then the property should be called something like `item.Registrations`, and it should not be of type `Registration`, it should be a list/collection type that *contains* `Registration` instances.

Comment: so whats the solution to the problem?

Comment: @Abu - First clarify what you are trying to do, then go from there.  As I noted, I really don't think you actually want to have `Registration` be an iterable class that contains a list of `Registration` instances.  You probably want to use something like an `ArrayList`, and put your `Registration` instances inside there.  Then you iterate the *list*, not the `Registration`.

Comment: have you seen the data model class rite, so what iam tyring to achieve is that how to iterate the list... thats consits of Registration...Students.... so forth...

Comment: You don't have lists consisting of `Registration`, `Student`, etc..  You have one list, which contains `MasterEmployee` elements.  And you're already iterating it with `foreach (MasterEmployee item in masterEmployee)`.  If you want to iterate the fields in each `MasterEmployee`, then you need to derive the class from `IEnumerable`, and you need to iterate it like:  `foreach (Object obj in item)`.

Answer (score 1):

The class should be derived from IEnumerable.

reference and examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: so there is no other way then implementing IEnumerable?

Comment: It's not a big deal. just change the declaration of your class into: "public class MasterEmployee : IEnumarable" and add a function public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {}

Comment: Sorry, it's late, i'm getting tired ;) class MasterEmployee is not the problem, class Registration is not a Collectionclass. I don't see the point though why you do a second foreach there, it's just a single value. class Registration is not in the codesnippet, though.